# iframe content not loading on Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, iframe

Just a basic iframe, it's a survey from Qualtrics.

```
<iframe src="https://something.com/something" width="90%" height="800px"></iframe>
```

Works fine on Firefox and Safari. On Chrome it says "sorry, an unexpected error occurred." where the embedded iframe is supposed to be. Confirmed same thing is happening on different Chrome devices we tested on. It's on a wordpress site. Been running this survey off and on for years and never had this issue before.